# Getting Error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when using my Cordova File Picker App

Tags: html, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-3, cordova-2.0.0

I am building a cordova application where the user can press a button and pick a file (here named as myfile.txt). Whenever i am pressing the 'Pick a file' button i am getting the error 'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED'. Yes, i did include the cordova file plugin into the project. I dont understand why it needs to connect to the internet. I did try giving permissions explicitly in the config.xml but then the build is getting failed so cannot do that.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElDAn.png)

My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
       
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover">
        <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
        <style>
            #btn{
                font-size: 1.5rem;
                line-height: 2.5rem;
                margin: 1rem;
            }

            .app{

                display:flex;
                flex-direction:column;
                align-items:center;
                text-align:center;

            }

        </style>
        <title>File App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <img src = "img/logo.png" alt=" image" id = "logo"/>
            <button id="btn">Pick a File</button>
        </div>

        <script>
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

            function onDeviceReady() {
                document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', pickFile);
            }


            function pickFile() {

                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory, function (dirEntry) {
                    dirEntry.getFile('myfile.txt', { create: false }, function (fileEntry) {
                        if (fileEntry) {
                            fileEntry.file(function (file) {
                                alert('File picked: ' + file.name);
                            }, onError);
                        } else {
                            createFile();
                        }
                    }, onError);
                }, onError);
            }

            function createFile() {
                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory, function (dirEntry) {
                    dirEntry.getFile('myfile.txt', { create: true }, function (fileEntry) {
                        // File created successfully
                    }, onError);
                }, onError);
            }


            function onError(error) {
                console.error('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            }

        </script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

My Config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.fileApp" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>FileApp</name>
    <description>Sample Apache Cordova App</description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="https://cordova.apache.org">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    
</widget>
```